# Wordpress - Individual pages as sections on front-page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, sections

I created multiple pages like services, about, our team... in wordpress and i can modify content of those pages creating individual php files for each page like page-services.php or page-about.php so i can use advanced custom fields plugin in those pages. But what i need to do now i to include those pages as sections in my front-page or static-page so those previous pages are actually sections in my front-page. And i try to do this with get_template_part() and with get_post() and get_page() and include() but nothing is working. I look for answer all over internet but i just cant find it and i think it should be very simple. I rly appreciate any help.

```
<div id="service" class="text-center">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p><?php the_field('service_subtitle'); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php if(get_field('service_box')): 

            while(has_sub_field('service_box')): ?>

            <div class="col-sm-4 column-box  wow fadeInUp  animated" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                <h3><?php  echo the_sub_field('service_box_title'); ?></h3>
                <div class="title-line"></div>
                <p><?php  echo the_sub_field('service_box_content'); ?></p>
            </div>

        <?php   endwhile;

        else :

            // no rows found

        endif;

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code on service page or in page-service.php file. And now i need to include this page or this code in my front page. Also i have multiple pages (sections) like this which i need to include in my front page also. End i dont want to just copy this and rest of code in front-page i wont it to be on separate pages and then include those pages in front page.

Comment: You can edit the code of your front-page. Add a section in the php files, you have those pages ID, so query the pages content and insert to new section.

Comment: Can you give me example how to include lets say services page in front-page. And id is services.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Comment: Assume you can find a way to include page-service.php to your front-page, the code in service page will not work as expected. For ex "<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>" will show the title of front-page, not service page.

Comment: Can you maybe suggest me some other way i can do this.

Comment: Yea i guess there is no other way then coding everything on front-page to create one page website. Thanks anyway dude.

Comment: Have you try to use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-pages/ ?

Comment: I have just tried the plugin, and i inserted this in front-page content [insert page='service' display='all'] but it shows content without any css or html structure i have on my service page. Also it shows names of acf plugin fields and next to them content of those fields and all content is in ul>li structure. Also in front-page php file i used normal loop to show content and offcourse it is set to static-page. So any suggestions what may be the problem?

Comment: Also i tried to use it like template [insert page='section' display='section.php'] (section.php is template) but it loads for 20 seconds and this happened  Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\advanced-custom-fields\acf.php on line 315

Comment: But the subtitle field loads correctly with proper css, html clases and all.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the page content based on ID and insert to your current front-page code. Like the code below.

```
<?php
// Assume that the Id of the page you need to include is 7.
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'include' => '7', 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue;

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
<?php
}   
?>
```

Comment: Its not working and i changed id to 33. This is my page url http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=33&action=edit

Comment: Problem is if page-services.php i have echo the_content when i include that page in font-page like get_template_part('page-services') it shows content of front-page not service page. Plus i have custom fields in each page that shows in individual pages but not when i include those pages in my front-page

Comment: I cannot reach your localhost. You need to put those code to php file according to your front-age, not edit the page content. Another alternative way is try to use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-pages/